# Libgit2sharp clone repo with progressbar

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, libgit2sharp

Can anyone guide me how to get progress of clone a git repo more than 1gb from public url

While cloning

Repository.clone("url");

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
using LibGit2Sharp.Handlers;
using LibGit2Sharp;


// Define source/dest
var source = "https://github.com/org/blah.git";
var dest = "c:\\temp\\blah\\";

// Clone fails if destination already exists
if (Directory.Exists(dest))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Directory exists and is not an empty directory, please fix and try again.");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}

// Create a delegate to handle progress events
var gitProgress = new ProgressHandler((serverProgressOutput) =>
{
    // Print output to console
    Console.Write(serverProgressOutput);

    // Move cursor to beginning of line
    (int left, int top) = Console.GetCursorPosition();
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0,top);

    return true;
});

// Clone repo using progress handler
var x = Repository.Clone(source, dest, new CloneOptions { OnProgress = gitProgress });
```